# Variables in Python

Tags: python, variables

Here is a little script:

```
class Any(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x=x

l = [Any(2),Any(3),Any(7),Any(9),Any(10)]
print(len(l))
l2=[ind for ind in l]
l3=l
print(set(l2).difference(l3))
print(l2[1]==l[1])
print(l3[1]==l[1])
del l2[1]
print(len(l))
del l3[1]
print(len(l))
```

Why deleting an instance of `Any` in `l2` doesn't change `l`, but deleting it in `l3`changes `l` although it seems not to have any difference between l2 and l3?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `l3` and `l` are just two names for the *same* list...

Comment: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`l2` is a *different* object created from `l`

`l3` refers to the *same* object as `l`. So changing anything in `l` or `l3` will affect that object and therefore will affect `l` and `l3`.

Comment: `l2` is a different object but both `l` and `l2`are lists of the same `objects`. Therefore, modifying `l[2]` modifies `l2[2]` but modifying `l` does not modify `l2`. Is it something like that?

Comment: By deleting `l2[1]` you are not actually changing `l2[1]` object, you are removing second element from the list.

Answer (score 5):

Because:

```
>>> l is l2
False
>>> l is l3
True
```

Binding the reference twice makes both names refer to the same object.